# Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined Evaluating App.js Loading App.js

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Looking to have button enter go into another screen:
need help with navigation screen.
I keep getting  error:
Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined
Evaluating App.js
Loading App.js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined

https://snack.expo.io/@ganiyat1/colorful-thrills

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Books from './components/Books';

// You can import from local files

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';


const Book = StackNavigator({
  Books: { screen: Books },
});
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    
      <View style={styles.topContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.title}> Colorful Thrills
    </Text >
      </View>
      <View style={styles.bottomContainer}></View>
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={require('./assets/bookcover.png')}
        />
         
         <Text style={styles.paragraph}> 
     {"\n"}  BOOKWORMS, UNITE! {"\n"} {"\n"}
      Suspense, Mystery and Thrillers by Authors of Color
      </Text>
      <Button 
      color='#ff914d'
      title= 'ENTER'
      onPress={() =>
          navigate('Books')}
      />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above code snippet, I don't see a default `Navigator` being returned form the entry file, which is `App.js` by default in *React Native*.

I assume that you just started to learn React Native, so I will spare you all the minor details and walk you through the solution.

1. I refactored the `App.js` file to a into a new component file in `/components/Home.js`.
2. Added a default stack `Navigator` in `App.js` which has two screens, Home and Books.
3. Now you can access all the `Navigation` props in your `Home` and `Books` component, as it is being declared in the Navigator variable in `App.js`

Here is a live demo of your code on [Expo](https://snack.expo.io/@ajinkabeer/colorful-thrills).

```js
//App.js

import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Books from './components/Books';
import Home from './components/Home'
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';


const Navigator = StackNavigator({
  Books: { screen: Books },
  Home:{screen:Home}
});
 
export default function App(props) {
   return (
   <Navigator /> 
  );
}
```

```js
//component/Books.js

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView,Button } from 'react-native';
import MaterialTabs from 'react-native-material-tabs';

const Books = (props) => {
  const {navigation} = props
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState(0);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <MaterialTabs
        items={['New Releases', 'All', 'BOM']}
        selectedIndex={selectedTab}
        onChange={setSelectedTab}
        barColor="#1fbcd2"
        indicatorColor="#ff914d"
        activeTextColor="white"
      />

        <Button 
      color='#ff914d'
      title= 'Home'
      onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate('Home')}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default Books
```

```js
//component/Home.js
import React from 'react'
import {View,Text,StyleSheet,Button,Image} from 'react-native' 

const Home = (props) => {
  const {navigation} = props
  return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
    
      <View style={styles.topContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.title}> Colorful Thrills
    </Text >
      </View>
      <View style={styles.bottomContainer}></View>
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={require('../assets/bookcover.png')}
        />
         
         <Text style={styles.paragraph}> 
     {"\n"}  BOOKWORMS, UNITE! {"\n"} {"\n"}
      Suspense, Mystery and Thrillers by Authors of Color
      </Text>
      <Button 
      color='#ff914d'
      title= 'ENTER'
      onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate('Books')}
      />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Home

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  topContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ff914d',
  },
  bottomContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#96d0e3',
  },
  imageContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  image: {
    width: 300,
  },
  title:{
     margin: 24,
    marginTop: 50,
    fontSize: 40,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'GillSans-Italic',
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    marginTop: 0,
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  }
});
```

Comment: yes I just started learning react native two weeks ago.  so would it be export default function App(props) {
  return <Navigator />;
  <View style={styles.container}>? I tried different variations but i'm still getting errors

Comment: I don't think you need to return the `<View>` component at all. Just return the `Navigator` from the App.js file. ```export default function App() { return <Navigator />}```

Comment: I am having a similar issue but by error is: "Cannot redefine property: ThemeProvider
  Evaluating react-navigation.js
  Evaluating App.js
  Loading App.js" 

would the solution to this be the same as above?